# Check whether a sequence converges to a point in a given metric space

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Does the sequence $x_n = (t/8)^n-(t/8)^{2n} +t$ converge to the point $a=t$ in a metric space $C[0,8]$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the space is $(C[0,8],\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ where $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is the uniform norm, the answer is no:

Define $f_n : [0,8] \to \mathbb{R}$ as $f_n(t) = \left(\frac{t}{8}\right)^n - \left(\frac{t}{8}\right)^{2n}+ t, \forall t \in [0,8]$.

$$\|f_n(t) - t\|_\infty = \left\|\left(\frac{t}{8}\right)^n - \left(\frac{t}{8}\right)^{2n}\right\|_\infty = \sup_{t\in [0,8]}\left|\left(\frac{t}{8}\right)^n - \left(\frac{t}{8}\right)^{2n}\right| = \sup_{x\in[0,1]}\left|x^n-x^{2n}\right| = \frac{1}{4} \nrightarrow 0$$

The supremum of $g(x) = x^n - x^{2n}$ can be found by taking the derivative:

$$0 = g'(x) = n x^{n-1} - 2nx^{2n-1} \implies x = \frac{1}{2^n}$$
$$g\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right) = \frac{1}{4}$$

Since $g(0) = g(1) = 0$, it is indeed the supremum on $[0,1]$.

Comment: could U elaborate a lil bit more on this, and also give some links on theoretical stuff

Comment: @NiHao92 I just used the definition of convergence: $f_n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} f$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty }\|f_n - f\|_\infty = 0$. In our case, I calculated $\|f_n - f\|_\infty$ and noticed that it does not converge to $0$, as it is a constant sequence $\frac{1}{4}$. Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm).

Comment: could U add a few lines on the norm itself, $|| some mathematical expression here ||$, how it is being calculated, definition, or link to some book/website where I can read more about it

Comment: @NiHao92 I gave you the link on Uniform norm, read about it there. In this case it is defined as $$\|f\|_\infty = \sup_{x\in [0,8]} |f(x)|$$. Since $f$ is continuous, it attains its maximum on a segment, so you can in fact write $$\|f\|_\infty = \max_{x\in [0,8]} |f(x)|$$
If $f$ happens to be differentiable, like in your example, then you can calculate the supremum by finding all $x_0$ such that $0 = f'(x_0)$. The supremum will be the maximal value $f(x_0)$, or the value $f(0), f(8)$ on the boundary of the segment, whichever has the largest absolute value.